# J-K Flip Flop Output

Tags: flipflop

For a J-K Flip Flop, once we have J&K=1, now when the CLK Goes high, so Output goes high on the falling edge, but when does the OUTPUT Goes back to LOW?

Comment: Are you asking about JK flip-flop or JK edge-triggered-flip-flop? There is difference between these terms. Maybe this post will be helpful to you: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/74986/edge-triggering-seems-to-me-leaving-every-circuit-in-an-inconsistent-state/74991#74991

Answer (score 1):

On the next falling edge, assuming both inputs are still high. The synchronous inputs (J and K) are synchronized with the clock.

Answer (score 0):

When Both Inputs of JK FlipFlop are High, It goes in Toggle Mode i.e. Q = Q'.

So, Assuming it's Falling Edge Triggered flipflop, On Next Falling Edge, Output will be LOW again. And On next Falling edge, it will be HIGH again and so on...

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#JK_flip-flop) article has this table and timing diagram.